# Regex to remove string in between delimiters

Tags: .net, regex, string, parsing

I am trying to get rid of the delimited text.

For Example:  "this#101# is#102# a#103# test#104#"

Result : "this is a test"

Tried the Following which didn;t Work

```
string Pattern = @"(?<=#).*(?=#;)";
string text = "this#101# is#102# a#103# test#104#";
text = Regex.Replace(text, Pattern, string.Empty);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
string Pattern = @"#.*?#";
```

Since you need to get rid of the `#` too, you need to specify them as matching part of the regex. Your current regex does not match the `#`.

Also you need to make the `.*` match non-greedy by adding a trailing `?`.